# How do I add a video layer with alpha channel (transparency) to an iphone app?

Tags: iphone, ipad, video, transparency, alpha

I would like to add a video of a moving object to a background that can be changed, what format should I use? How should I implement this?

EDIT: I would like to make an effect like this:[image: Sample image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done using making animations manually. I converted the frames to png(which supports alpha channel) and played the frames with a fixed frame rate.
I did not find any video that supports an alpha channel.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just make it an animation? I'm sure with enough frames it could look smooth enough.

```
NSArray *myImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
    [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage1.png"],
    [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage2.png"],
    [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage3.png"],
    [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage4.gif"],
    nil];

UIImageView *myAnimatedView = [UIImageView alloc];
[myAnimatedView initWithFrame:[self bounds]];
myAnimatedView.animationImages = myImages;
myAnimatedView.animationDuration = 0.25; // seconds
myAnimatedView.animationRepeatCount = 0; // 0 = loops forever
[myAnimatedView startAnimating];
[self addSubview:myAnimatedView];
[myAnimatedView release];
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I did in the end.